IngestionTimestamp contains %3A symbol instead of semicolon
In my Azure Blob Storage I have a folder named as IngestionTimestamp in ISO 8601 format. But I want to have the semicolons in time part. Instead, I get the %3A symbols.
I've tried to use the urllib.parse unquote Python library to decode the string.
Also, I use the datetime library to format the timestamp
current_timestamp_str = current_timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
decoded_timestamp = unquote(current_timestamp_str + '+00:00')
In VS Code it shows me the timestamp with semicolons. But when I land data into Blob container, I have the folder name like this:
IngestionTimestamp=2021-01-01T01%3A20%3A33.
I want this:
IngestionTimestamp=2021-01-01T01:20:33+00:00

Code with transforming date/time format:
    current_date = date.today()
    current_date_str = str(current_date)
    current_timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    current_timestamp_str = current_timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    decoded_timestamp = unquote(current_timestamp_str + '+00:00')


How did you actually check the output? It looks more like it was quoted somewhere later.

I print the variable 'decoded_timestamp' in Terminal in VSCode and it shows the correct output of Timestamp I want. But it changes in Azure Blob Storage. I don't know, maybe Azure automatically converts this?

Could you please add the full code how you are renaming the folder?

current_timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
current_timestamp_str = current_timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
decoded_timestamp = unquote(current_timestamp_str + '+00:00')

Add the full code in question with proper details.

The provided code does not print any URL encoded characters, with and without unquote().

@Kramer Check the below answer.

@Venkatesan Thanks for your answer. I responded under you answer.

@Venkatesan to generate folder hierarchy with IngestionDate and IngestionTimestamp columns, I used the partitionBy() function in PySpark. I removed that function and I only pass a string which contains full path with date/time fields. And now the problem with encoded characters were solved! Thanks to everyone for time and effort to solve this problem


In VS Code, it shows me the timestamp with semicolons. However, when I land data into the Blob container, I have the folder name like this: IngestionTimestamp=2021-01-01T01%3A20%3A33. I want this: IngestionTimestamp=2021-01-01T01:20:33+00:00

You can use the code below to create a directory(folder) with your specific format in Azure storage using Python.
Code:
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import urllib.parse
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

current_timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
current_timestamp_str = current_timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').replace(';', ':')
encoded_timestamp_str = urllib.parse.quote(current_timestamp_str + '+00:00', safe=';/?:@&=+$,-_.!~*()')

folder_name = 'IngestionTimestamp=' + encoded_timestamp_str

connection_string = 'xxxxx'
filesystem_name = 'data'

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(filesystem_name)
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(folder_name)
directory_client.create_directory()

Output:

Update:
You can use the below code to rename the folder.
Code:
from datetime import datetime,timezone
import urllib.parse
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

current_timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
current_timestamp_str = current_timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').replace(';', ':')
encoded_timestamp_str = urllib.parse.quote(current_timestamp_str + '+00:00', safe=';/?:@&=+$,-_.!~*()')

new_folder_name = 'IngestionTimestamp=' + encoded_timestamp_str

connection_string = 'xxxx'
filesystem_name = 'data'
foldername="sample123"

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(filesystem_name)
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(foldername)
directory_client.rename_directory(
        new_name=f"{directory_client.file_system_name}/{new_folder_name}") 

Reference:
Use Python to manage data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

Thanks for your response. I've tried to run the part of your code about encoding timestamp and no changes I get this:
IngestionTimestamp=2024-04-23T10%3A03%3A51+00%3A00/
I don't use the Python SDK to work with Azure Blob Storage. I save it by using Pyspark and save it to the Databricks file system

Edit the question and add the full pyspark code.
